# How can I know if my laptop is getting enough power?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have removed my laptop’s battery because it was swelling up and damaging other components of the laptop.

I am running my laptop directly through power adapter. I have connected my power adapter in a extension cord somewhat like that in the image.

[image]

I feel that my laptop power has reduced due to the extension cord  as a router is also connected to that extension

Is there any way through which I can know if my laptop is getting enough power?

Comment: Why do you think more than one item connected to an extension cord would lower power? The reality is the voltage you get in any home is way more than a router or a laptop power supply would ever use.

Comment: What type of laptop? Some (Apple for example) throttle CPU if no battery is connected which will make it run slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways you can know this. The easiest is to stress test the laptop - if it doesn't crash its getting enough power.

That said, I think your fears are unfounded (ie the charger output is fine) for a couple of reasons -

1. The less current you are pulling through a cable the loss. Even a power hubgry laptop (say one drawing 110 watts) on a 110 volt power supply would only be drawing 1 amp - which is 1/10th the rating if the cable. This is close to a worst realistic case scenario because the problem is halved at 220 volts, and because there is no battery to charge the draw will be less.
2. The charger will have a wide range of input voltage and will correct to the appropriate voltage. (The current drawn will be what us required).

Your battery was likely faulty and its good you removed it. Its unlikely that an extension cable caused the problem - if anything a lower current would decrease the stress on the battery.